# Is there an easier way to change application ID and name?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store

I have forked existing react-native application which is already uploaded to appstore and I want to create another application based on this application. I couldn't find any references on changing bundle ID with Application name.

I have tried to manually replace `oldAppName` to `newAppName` with global replace in `iOS` folder, but after replacing, cleaning, reinstalling, I cannot run the app with `react-native run-ios` it's saying that I should try to build with XCode to see more detailed error, but in XCode project is running fine.

P.S This is how I reset, clear and reinstall after replacing `oldAppName`:

```
watchman watch-del-all &&  rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && yarn cache clean && cd ios && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf assets && rm -rf build && pod cache clean --all && cd .. && rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*

yarn install && cd ios && pod install && cd ..

react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.js --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

All I need is detach from forked app to get new bundler ID for FireBase and have no references left to old application.

Any suggestions or should I just continue with the way I was doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the link which you are searching for.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) Go for it.

Comment: That was easier than i thought:D Thanks!

Comment: Works for iOS but doesn't work for Android if you pass a different pkg name :P The MainApplication.java package reference is not updated...