# My react native project cannot build after rename project

Tags: react-native

I tried to rename my app because I need it but I got the problem after rename it (it works fine before I rename it). I followed this instruction : https://dev.to/abdulbasit313/proper-way-to-rename-a-react-native-project-in-2019-3b98 but when I run, build failed

I'm using react native 0.59.9

This is the error :

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
> Task :app:preDebugBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
       - file:/D:/3-SIMASA/simasamobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - file:/D:/3-SIMASA/simasamobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-image-crop-picker

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
21 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 1 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned solution is not correct because it'll clear your linked libraries... You can easily rename the android project by changing `name` in `android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`. Also on iOS, you can change the name by opening `ios/your_project.xcodeproj` in Xcode and modify `Display Name` in the `General` tab of your project settings.

Answer (score 1):

Please install and relink the library again. This will resolve the issue.

[react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)

Also please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553417/is-there-an-easier-way-to-change-application-id-and-name/57554217#57554217) to how to rename project in easier way.